# Parallel Merge Sort in Scala

Tags: multithreading, sorting, scala, mergesort

I have been trying to implement parallel merge sort in Scala. My current implementation is about as fast as `.sorted`, but I have no idea what would be the right aproach to parallelize it.

Input file with 1.2M integers:

- 1.333580 seconds (my implementation)
- 1.439293 seconds (`.sorted`)

How should I parallelize this?

```
object Mergesort extends App
{

//=====================================================================================================================
// UTILITY
  implicit object comp extends Ordering[Any] {
    def compare(a: Any, b: Any) = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (a: Int, b: Int)       => a compare b
        case (a: String, b: String) => a compare b
        case _                      => 0
      }
    }
  }

//=====================================================================================================================
// MERGESORT

  val THRESHOLD = 30

  def inssort[A](a: Array[A], left: Int, right: Int): Array[A] = {
    for (i <- (left+1) until right) {
      var j = i
      val item = a(j)
      while (j > left && comp.lt(item,a(j-1))) {
        a(j) = a(j-1)
        j -= 1
      }
      a(j) = item
    }
    a
  }

  def mergesort_merge[A](a: Array[A], temp: Array[A], left: Int, right: Int, mid: Int) : Array[A] = {
    var i = left
    var j = right
    while (i < mid) { temp(i) = a(i);   i+=1;       }
    while (j > mid) { temp(i) = a(j-1); i+=1; j-=1; }

    i = left
    j = right-1
    var k = left
    while (k < right) {
      if (comp.lt(temp(i), temp(j))) { a(k) = temp(i); i+=1; k+=1; }
      else                           { a(k) = temp(j); j-=1; k+=1; }
    }
    a
  }

  def mergesort_split[A](a: Array[A], temp: Array[A], left: Int, right: Int): Array[A] = {
    if (right-left == 1) a

    if ((right-left) > THRESHOLD) {
      val mid = (left+right)/2
      mergesort_split(a, temp, left, mid)
      mergesort_split(a, temp, mid, right)
      mergesort_merge(a, temp, left, right, mid)
    }
    else
      inssort(a, left, right)
  }

  def mergesort[A: ClassTag](a: Array[A]): Array[A] = {
    val temp = new Array[A](a.size)
    mergesort_split(a, temp, 0, a.size)
  }
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know Scala. You seem to be creating an awful lot of `List`s and `Future`s. Whenever you create a `Future` it has to go onto the thread pool and wait until it can be processed, that's a lot of overhead. Ideally you would split the whole task into `Runtime.availableProcessors` futures to save on thread scheduling overhead. Scala `List` is an immutable linked list and has terrible random access times (presumably used when splitting).

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the piece of code and now it's almost as fast as sorted. Now parallelizing is the only thing missing

Comment: I implemented alternative mergesort using https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/03-13/MergeSort.java as a base. Single threaded performance is slower than mine, but it's easier to parallelize. bpaste.net/show/f93cf489ca08 I still don't know what would be the correct way to use scala futures. Currently I just fork,wait and merge